# How to keep only rows where the value of a specific column exists in a specified vector/series?

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

Let's assume I have a dataframe df1 with the columns ['Name', 'ISIN', 'Price'].
The ISINs are ['2', '4', '5', '7'].

The ISINs from df2 are ['1', '2', '3', '4'] which I have extracted into a series.
Let's call the series 'isinvector'.

How can I keep only the rows of df1 if the ISIN value exists in the extracted series?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values).

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1['ISIN'].isin(isinvector)]
```

would do the job.